# Difference in adding of elements to linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

This is how i add elements to the head of a linked list

```
 //typedef void* VoidPtr
 //typedef node* NodePtr
 struct Node
   {
       NodePtr next
       VoidPtr data
   };


void LinkedList::Addelement(VoidPtr horoscope)
{
    if(head == NULL)
  {

    head = new Node;
    head->data = horoscope;
     head->next = NULL;

  }

NodePtr temp = new Node;

temp -> data = horoscope;
temp -> next = head;

head = temp;
}
```

This is how i add elements to the tail of a linked list

```
void LinkedList::addelementfromback(VoidPtr horoscope)
{
   NodePtr temp=head;

   if(head == NULL)
   {

    head = new Node;
    head->data = horoscope;
    head->next = NULL;

   }

   while( temp->next != NULL)
   {
      temp=temp->next

   }

   NodePtr element=New Node;
   element->data=horoscope;
   element->next=NULL;

    temp->next=element;



}
```

i dont understand why we use temp=element for adding to the head of a linked list
but for adding to the tail of a linked list we use temp->next=element. I dont understand why we cant use while temp=next for adding element to tail of linked list

Comment: you don't use `while (temp != NULL)` for adding to the head of a linked list

Comment: Please enlightened me. It works though

Comment: What?  That expression isn't even in your example.

Comment: You should just draw yourself a picture and see what happens if you run the algorithm by hand.  Hint: if you check for `temp != NULL`, the loop breaks when `temp` *is* equal to `NULL`.  How would you get back from `NULL` to the last list node?

Comment: My bad i wrote wrongly, let me do edit it

Comment: @Computernerd: the tail of a list is the element whose `next` is NULL. That's what your loop is checking.

Comment: @Computernerd:  Save yourself some development headaches and use `std::list`.  It's already been thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Addelement` method, you need an `else` clause because if the list is empty (`head == NULL`), you only need to point the `head` to the new node.  Nothing else, there are no other nodes in the list.

Also, rather than using a *void pointer*, consider using **templates**.  Templates are great for data structures and algorithms where the data type changes, not the structure or algorithm, such as stacks and linked lists.

I suggest you consider separating the node pointers from the data item as two separate structures.  This will help you use common code between single linked lists and doubly linked lists.  Also a great help when you don't want to use templates.

```
struct Node_Link
{
    Node_Link * next;
};

struct Node_Integer
: public Node_Link
{
    int data;
};

struct Node_Double
: public Node_Link
{
   double data;
};

struct Node_String
: public Node_Link
{
    std::string data;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `addelementfromback`, `temp` is a pointer to the last element in the list. If you were to say `temp = element`, this wouldn't change the list, since you're just giving a local pointer a new value.

`temp->next`, however, is the `next` variable stored inside the object `temp` points to (i.e. the last element in the list), you need to change this value to point to the new element.

For `Addelement`, `temp` is a pointer to the new element, you assign the pointer `head` to point to the same element, and change the `next` variable inside this pointed-to element to point to the original head.